# At which places are JVM options hidden by STS software? How do I make the Java Hotspot MaxPermSize warning go away when using STS?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, java-8

I am using STS 3.6.0, Grails 2.4.4, Java 8 (JDK 1.8_05).
I have removed MaxPermSize options from JAVA_OPTS, MAVEN_OPTS and ini file of STS. It is still showing following warning and stops my application.

**"Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0"**

Also to note that I had set 256m only for MAVEN_OPTS which I have removed completely, but still I am having same problem.

I have even deleted forked build from BuildConfig.groovy file which specifies 256M as maxperm.

Extra info:

I am using jdk1.8_45

Comment: Wait—you say you have removed the warning *everywhere*? I can assert you that the warning does not appear when there is no such option specified. So maybe you should rephrase your question to “at which places are JVM options hidden by these software?” or “why does this software stop my application at a *warning*?”

Comment: check STS.ini or eclipse.ini file and remove the MaxPermSize setting

Comment: if you have solved this maybe you can answer your own question to help others

Comment: @Holger I will rephrase my question.

Comment: @Neoryder I have removed that from STS.ini and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Find the STS.ini file.

remove

```
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=712m
```

Sample STS.ini file

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xmn128m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-Xss4m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=712m
-XX:CompileThreshold=1000
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/sts.icns
-Dgrails.console.enable.interactive=false
-Dgrails.console.enable.terminal=false
-Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal
-Dgrails.console.class=grails.build.logging.GrailsEclipseConsole
```

Comment: I have already tried but still stuck with warning and project not running

Comment: That is wierd since this is just a warning. This is probably not the reason that your program is not running. Let us test this by running grails in the command line.